# Do I need a visa for a connecting flight through Paris

Tags: air-france

I am going from Dubai to Canada. Paris is one of my connecting flight,do I need to get a visa here?

Comment: You haven't told us what nationality passport you will be traveling with, but in any case, see [Do I need a visa to transit in the Schengen area?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569).